# Invalid signature using bash flickr api, method flickr.auth.getToken

Tags: bash, flickr

I am trying to get a token to eventually get a list of photos using the 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos' method. To do so, I need to get a token.

EDIT: Here is the api for flickr.auth.getToken:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.auth.getToken.html

and for flickr.photosets.getPhotos:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Here is my script with my api_key and api_secret that I try to get a token:

```
#!/bin/bash

api_key="MY_KEY"
api_secret="MY_SECRET"
perms="read"
api_sig=`echo -n "${api_secret}api_key${api_key}perms${perms}" | md5sum | sed s/\ .*$//`
#md5_api_sig=`echo -n $api_sig | md5sum | sed s/\ .*$//`

echo "api_sig: $api_sig";
login_link="http://flickr.com/services/auth/?api_key=$api_key&api_sig=$api_sig&perms=$perms"

echo "login_link: $login_link";
echo "Enter frob: ";
read frob;
flickr_method="flickr.auth.getToken"
api_sig="${api_secret}api_key${api_key}frob${frob}method${flickr_method}"
echo "api_sig: $api_sig"
api_sig_md5=`echo $api_sig | md5sum | sed s/\ .*$//`
echo "api_sig_md5: $api_sig_md5";

api_url="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=${api_key}&api_sig=${api_sig_md5}&frob=${frob}&method=${flickr_method}"

echo
echo "api link: $api_url";
```

My problem is when I paste the frob into my script and get the `api_url` above and put that in my browser, it gives me:

```
<rsp stat="fail">
<err code="96" msg="Invalid signature"/>
</rsp>
```

Does anyone have any insight on what could be going on? I believe I have all arguments in the correct places. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely not the type of question we like to answer here, but you could at least make it a little bit answerer-friendly by linking to the API endpoint documentation.

Comment: I've added these links. If you think this belongs somewhere else, why not just tell me in which stack* it actually belongs? I can just remove this and create it there.

Comment: I can't tell you because I think it belongs nowhere. (Technically speaking it kinda belongs here, but as I said no one wants to answer this type of question. We solve problems here, but we're not free coders for hire.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not asking for code here. I'm asking if someone has any insight on what I may be doing wrong here. I didn't ask for someone to write this for me as I've presented it in a pretty easy way to read it. Thanks for your "free coders for hire" spiel.